IIFE incompatibility with semi-colon JS
Can someone explain this JS behavior?
When inside of IIFE, a statement like
document.body.appendChild(s_host) wouldn't work without a semi-colon
Having an error of Uncaught TypeError: document.body.appendChild(...) is not a function
And when I put a semi-colon after the statement but do not with my IIFE inside,
It will produce Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(...) is not a function
The unexpected behavior
(() => {
    const s_host = document.createElement("div")
    const s_root = s_host.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed' })    
    document.body.appendChild(s_host)
    // Uncaught TypeError: document.body.appendChild(...) is not a function
    
    // Button for clear storage
    (() => {
        let storage = chrome.storage.local
        const clear_button = document.createElement("button")    
        clear_button.setAttribute("style",
            `   position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                height: 20px;
                width: 40px;
                background-color: green;
                border: 1px solid black;            
            `)
        clear_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            storage.get(null, data => {
                console.log("Storage before clearing: ")
                console.log(data)
                storage.clear(() => {
                    if(chrome.runtime.lastError){
                        console.error("Storage has not been cleared", chrome.runtime.lastError)
                    } else {
                        storage.get(null, data => console.log("Storage successfully cleared: ", data))
                    }
                })
            })
        })
        s_root.appendChild(clear_button)
    })()
    Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(...) is not a function

Otherwise, it's working well. I'm just curious and I think this is the right place to ask.

Also if I add let data_placeholder = {} before the IIFE, it's producing the same error. So, I guess I should always put a semi-colon before and after IIFE

You could just put semicolons at the end of the lines. Or even better - set your linter to do it for you automatically.

nobody has 9.6kbaud modems for internet any more ... use semi-colons where you should, and you'll never have this issue again

In addition to what @JaromandaX said, the code can be minified, making it far more efficient than dropping (at most) one character per line.

I can do that, and I'm aware of the solution. That's why I'm specifically asking for an explanation for this JS behavior and the top link helped. I'm just curious.

the reason is syntax
